# Horizontal sub heading with vertical navigation

Tags: html, css

I am looking for some help with my navigation. 
I would like to have a horizontal navigation, and when hovering over a link, a sub nav will drop down with different sections (left and right for example), the 2 headings will be horizontal and under the headings there will be vertical sub navigations. 
It's kind of difficult for me to explain so I will attach a picture I created to try and explain it better.

http://i.imgur.com/VYfp14e.png
(unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to post an image straight onto stack overflow.

So hovering over heading 1 will drop down 2 horizontal headings (sub head 1 & 2)

Under subhead1 & 2 will be the vertical clickable links which will navigate the user to different pages.

(forgot the link to the fiddle). 
http://jsfiddle.net/8La4k57q/

```
 <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Heading 1</a>
        <ul>
        <a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">subHeading 1</a>
            <li><a href="#">Nav1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav4</a></li>

        <a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">subHeading 2</a>
            <li><a href="#">Nav5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
#nav > a
{
    display: none;
}
#nav li
{
    position: relative;
}



#nav > ul
{
    height: 3.75em;
}
    #nav > ul > li
    {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }



#nav li ul
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
    #nav li:hover ul
    {
        display: block;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add HTML in your question.

Comment: Hi sorry, I forgot the link! http://jsfiddle.net/8La4k57q/

Answer (score 0):

Well ..Lets take heading 1 for example, Here id heading1 will be used for the div with the heading and id content will be used for the div with the content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#heading1").mouseover(function(){
$("#content1").stop().slideDown();
});
$("#heading1").mouseout(function(){
$("#content1").slideUp();
});
});
```

The content im referring to is your subgheadings and your links enclosed in a div called content1.
I can explain better if u posted your html code.

Comment: HI, thanks for the help, I forgot the link to the fiddle. it is now added :)